# Finding the pixel positions for the straight line joining two points

Tags: graphics

Please help me solve the given problem.

> Find the pixel positions for the straight line joining P1 (10, 20) and P2 (18, 25)

Comment: There are different ways to draw your line, but one interesting approach (Bresenham's algorithm) is explained nicely in [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45753/bresenhams-line-algorithm).

Comment: see also: [Shading squares crossed by a diagonal](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4436/125)

Comment: Do you want a list of the discrete pixels needed to draw the line segment?

Answer (score 0):

```
a P1 + (1-a) P2 for 0 < a < 1.
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate it #David.

Comment: I think the OP wants a list of the discrete pixels needed to draw the line segment. If I'm right, this doesn't quite do the job.