# A bug in Rasterize and Graphics: diagonal line is under-diagonal

Tags: graphics, bugs, image, conversion, rendering

I plot a straight diagonal line and then simply rasterize it. Consider what happens (*Mathematica* 8.0.4, 10.2, 11.1.1 and 12.0 on Windows 7 x64):

```
n = 20;
gr = Graphics[{White, AbsoluteThickness[1], Line[{{0, 0}, {n, n}}]}, Background -> Black, 
   PlotRangePadding -> None, BaseStyle -> Antialiasing -> False, ImageSize -> {n, n}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, n}, {0, n}}];
i = Image[gr, Magnification -> 10]
Show[i, gr, BaseStyle -> Magnification -> 10]
```

[image: screenshot]

As it is clearly seen, the diagonal white `Line` is converted to under-diagonal line by `Rasterize`. Is it a bug or I misunderstand something?

Comment: It seems to me that you override the `BaseStyle -> Antialiasing -> False` setting when you use `Show`, and this causes problems.

Comment: @shrx With `Show[i, gr, BaseStyle -> {Magnification -> 10, Antialiasing -> False}]` and `Magnify[Show[i, gr], 10]` I get the same problem with additional bug: empty white space after the the output.

Comment: There are many alignment problems like this, unfortunately.

Answer (score 6):

A bit of investigation.

The first what come to mind is that the described bug is a result of incorrect conversion between the *coordinates* in `Graphics` and the *pixel positions* in `Image`. Typically they are shifted by `1/2` relative to each other, the latter having vertical positions counted from the top to the bottom.

Checking:

```
n = 20; d = .5;
gr[d_] := Graphics[{White, AbsoluteThickness[1], Line[{{0 - d, d}, {n - d, n + d}}]}, 
   Background -> Black, PlotRangePadding -> None, BaseStyle -> Antialiasing -> False, 
   ImageSize -> {n, n}, PlotRange -> {{0, n}, {0, n}}];
i = Image[gr[d], Magnification -> 10]
```

[image: screenshot]

Works! But what if we use another value for `d`? Experimenting shows that we get the same picture for `d` from `.3106` to `.8105` inclusively! But already for `d = .3105` and `d = .8106` the picture is different:

```
Grid[Map[Labeled[Image[gr[#], Magnification -> 10], Row[{"d=", #}], 
    Top] &, {{.3105, .3106}, {.8105, .8106}}, {2}], Frame -> All]
```

[image: screenshot]

What a strange threshold! Apparently `Rasterize` does not use the [Bresenham's line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm).